# instead of proper value html code is coming in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, ajaxform

I have an issue with JQuery. We are entering `test%` in the textfield and called one function on save button.In this function we are serialzing the form data and called AJAX then at server side it is coming as `test&#37;`. It is HTML code for `%`

Could you please help me to resolve the same. I am not able to understand how this is coming.
Below is the code.

```
function onSave(thisHref)
{
  var respData = "";
  var id = $("#id").attr("value");
  var params = $("#form_used").serialize()+"&ajaxAction=SaveHeader"+"&id="+id;
  $.post(ajaxURL, params, function(data){
    if(data.length >0) 
    {
      respData = data.substring(data.indexOf("|")+1, data.lastIndexOf("|"));
    }
  }).complete(function(){ 
    if (respData.length > 0)
    {
      var responseData = respData.split("|");
      var status = responseData[0];
      var msg = responseData[1];
      if (status == 'SUCCESS')
      {
        showSuccessMsgHeader(msg);
      }
      else if (status == 'ERROR')
      {
        showErrorMsgsOnly(msg);
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.serializeArray()` instead of `serialize()` function

Comment: thank you @Dev .I tried using the serializeArray method but now getting 400 Bad request error. I checked the form data in network tab and found that it is showing as “unable to decode value”  beside input field .

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's escape & unescape method
Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var str="Hello test&#37;!";
var str_esc=escape(str);
document.write(unescape(str_esc))

</script>

</body>
</html>
```